# Qt foreach with templates with multiple parameters

Tags: c++, qt

I came across a problem with a qt foreach and a template with multiple template parameters.

```
QVector<Node<T, U> > nodes;
...
[append some data]
...
foreach(const Node<T, U>& node, nodes) {
  ...
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
error: use of undeclared identifier 'Q_FOREACH'
```

I guess that it is due to the `,` in the template because the Qt macro does not detect that it inside another template declaration. How can I fix that without using normal for loops or C++11?

Comment: is `Node<T,U>` a qt container class?

Comment: have you tried typedef ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496842/pass-method-with-template-arguments-to-a-macro

Comment: have a similar issue when using a `QVector<QMap<int,int>>`
try `Node<T,U> node;
foreach( node, nodes ) {...}`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your compiler supports C++11, you could use

```
foreach(auto node, nodes) { ... }
```

or even

```
for(auto node: nodes) { ... }
```

Otherwise, you can force the preprocessor to ignore the comma in the template like this:

```
#define COMMA ,
foreach(const Node<T COMMA U>& node, nodes) { ... }
```

Or you can use a typedef

```
typedef Node<T, U> NodeTU;
foreach(const NodeTU& node, nodes) { ... }
```