# How to pass multi-argument templates to macros?

Tags: c++, templates, macros

Say I have a macro like this:

```
#define SET_TYPE_NAME(TYPE, NAME) \
    template<typename T>          \
    std::string name();           \
                                  \
    template<>                    \
    std::string name<TYPE>() {    \
        return NAME;              \
    }
```

This won't work if I pass it a template that has more than one parameter, because the comma in the `<int, int>` is interpreted as separating the *macro* arguments, not the template arguments.

```
SET_TYPE_NAME(std::map<int, int>, "TheMap")
// Error: macro expects two arguments, three given
```

This problem seems to be solved by doing this:

```
SET_TYPE_NAME((std::map<int, int>), "TheMap")
```

But now another problem arises, one that I really did not expect:

```
 template<>
 std::string name<(std::map<int, int>)>()
 // template argument 1 is invalid
```

It seems that the extra parentheses make the template argument invalid. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Besides `typedef`, you could switch the order of the arguments and use variadic macros (requires C99 or C++11-compatible compiler):

```
#define SET_TYPE_NAME(NAME, ...) \
template<typename T>          \
std::string name();           \
                              \
template<>                    \
std::string name<__VA_ARGS__>() {    \
    return NAME;              \
}
```

...

```
SET_TYPE_NAME("TheMap", std::map<int, int>)
```

Comment: Just C++11, unless C99 added `template` while we weren't looking.

Comment: @KennyTM: Damned, one minute ahead of me!

Comment: @MikeDeSimone: __VA_ARGS__ was introduced in C99, so a C++ compiler  (e.g. gcc 4.2) could support it in C++ as a non-standard extension.

Comment: @KennyTM Wasn't this added to C++11 as well?

Comment: @PaulManta: Yes, `__VA_ARGS__` is now standard in C++11, but a compiler may support it outside of C++11 mode because it also supports C99.

Answer (score 10):

You could use `typedef`:

```
typedef std::map<int, int> int_map;

SET_TYPE_NAME(int_map, "TheMap");
```

boost's [BOOST_FOREACH](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/foreach/pitfalls.html) suffers from the same issue.

Answer (score 7):

Some time ago (while searching the web for the utility of `Identity<T>`) I got to [this page](http://kaba.hilvi.org/pastel/techniques_deduction.htm).

In brief, to answer the question, if you don't have C++11 support and/or can't (or don't want to) use a `typedef`, you call your macro the "right" way:

```
// If an argument contains commas, enclose it in parentheses:
SET_TYPE_NAME((std::map<int, int>), "TheMap")
// For an argument that doesn't contain commas, both should work:
SET_TYPE_NAME((SomeType1), "TheType1")
SET_TYPE_NAME(SomeType2, "TheType2")
```

and then **to get rid of the (possible) unwanted parentheses around the type**, you can use a "helper" like this:

```
template<typename> struct RemoveBrackets;
template<typename T> struct RemoveBrackets<void (T)> {
    typedef T Type;
};
```

and in your macro change the line:

```
    std::string name<TYPE>() {    \
```

to:

```
    std::string name< RemoveBrackets<void (TYPE)>::Type >() {    \
```

(or define a helper macro, say

```
#define REMOVE_BRACKETS(x) RemoveBrackets<void (x)>::Type
```

then replace the line with

```
    std::string name< REMOVE_BRACKETS(TYPE) >() {    \
```

).

(For the full story read the paragraph "An even better solution" at the end of the article linked above.)

*Edit:* just found [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295890/trouble-with-template-parameters-used-in-macros/4298441#4298441). But it uses `<void X>` when it really should use `<void (X)>` (in `get_first_param<void X>::type`); indeed the parentheses *are* necessary if you pass a "simple", non-bracketed argument (like `SomeType2` in my code above) -- and they don't hurt if `X` is already bracketed (e.g., `void ((SomeType1))` is equivalent to `void (SomeType1)`; again, see the article). (By the way, I noticed that many answers on the other SO page are in essence "Macros are dumb". I won't comment, though.)

Comment: Edit: [Now you can just use `BOOST_IDENTITY_TYPE` (thanks to OP)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11701846/688659)

Comment: The link is down.

Comment: 'void ((SomeType1)) is equivalent to void (SomeType1)' -- why? Sorry, the link to the article is long dead.

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to add an answer to my own question. Now that Boost 1.50.0 was released, Boost.Utility has a new mini-library that helps with this kind of thing. If you look at the source you'll see it's implemented the same as [gx_'s solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11604267/627005). Here's how to use it:

```
#include <boost/utility/identity_type.hpp>
SET_TYPE_NAME(BOOST_IDENTITY_TYPE((std::map<int, int>)), "TheMap");
```

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/utility/identity_type/doc/html/index.html

Comment: _(I can leave comments now!)_ Thank you for the news :)

Answer (score 3):

I like the typedef way proposed by hmjd better, but for the record, the usual way I've seen around this is to kick the angle brackets out of the macro and write:

```
#define SET_TYPE_NAME(TYPE, NAME) \
    template<typename T>          \
    std::string name();           \
                                  \
    template<>                    \
    std::string name TYPE() {    \
        return NAME;              \
    }
```

Usage:

```
SET_TYPE_NAME(<std::map<int, int> >, "TheMap")
```

This is a variation of an old technique used for error message reporting and `fprintf`:

```
#define Error(args) do { \
    printf("ERROR: "); \
    printf args; \
    printf("\n"); \
    return 1; \
    } while(0)
```

Called with:

```
Error(("Index out of range: %d not in %d ... %d.", var, min, max));
```

It's ugly but it worked. Useful if the coding style rules ban `typedef`.

Comment: Interesting, but doesn't this raise the first error again? The one where the macro interprets the template as being two arguments.

Comment: Useful if the coding style rules ban `typedef` --> now you've got me worried.

Comment: Unfortunately, only parentheses, and not `<` and `>`, are recognised as brackets by the preprocessor, so this won't work.

Comment: @Matthieu M.: Example: [Linux Coding Style](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle), chapter 5: "In general, a pointer, or a struct that has elements that can reasonably
be directly accessed should _never_ be a typedef." @Mike Seymour: Even in C++? Are `[]` and `{}` recognized as brackets?

Answer (score 2):

```
typedef std::map<int,int> IntMap_t;
SET_TYPE_NAME(IntMap_t, "TheMap")
```

You can declare a typedef and use it in the macro

Answer (score 1):

A more generic way is to always use () around your arguments that may contain a comma and use CONCAT to remove the parenthesis. If you do so, you can define multiple parameters packs wits comma inside or put arguments in your favorite order

```
#ifndef CONCAT
#define CONCAT __VA_ARGS__
#endif

#define MYMACRO(tparam,classname)\
    template < CONCAT tparam >\
    class CONCAT classname {};

//create a template class X<T,U>
MYMACRO( (typename T,typename U) , (X<T,U>) )
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question. Though this comes in top results on a Google search and nobody has yet mentioned an even more simple solution by defining a macro for the comma:

```
#define COMMA ,
SET_TYPE_NAME(std::map<int COMMA int>, "TheMap")
```