# using boost foreach with items that are themselves templates

Tags: c++, boost, boost-foreach

I have a `std::deque< std::pair<int, int> >` that I would like to iterate over using `BOOST_FOREACH`.

I tried the following:

```
  #define foreach_ BOOST_FOREACH

  // declaration of the std::deque
  std::deque< std::pair<int, int> > chosen;

  foreach_( std::pair<int,int> p, chosen )
  {
     ... 
  }
```

But when I compile this (in Visual Studio ) I get the following errors:

```
warning C4002: too many actual parameters for macro 'BOOST_FOREACH'
1>c:\users\beeband\tests.cpp(133): error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '>'
1>c:\users\beeband\tests.cpp(133): error C2059: syntax error : '>'
1>c:\users\beeband\tests.cpp(133): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>c:\users\beeband\tests.cpp(133): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>c:\users\beeband\tests.cpp(133): error C2181: illegal else without matching if
```

What is the correct way to use `BOOST_FOREACH` with this `deque`?

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942912/how-to-pass-multi-argument-templates-to-macros), see answers there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the author of `BOOST_FOREACH`, I ask you to please stop using it. It was a hack whose time has come and gone. Please, please, please use C++11's range-base for loops and let `BOOST_FOREACH` die.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is the `,` as it is being used by the preprocessor to separate the macro arguments.

Possible solutions using `typedef`:

```
typedef std::pair<int, int> int_pair_t;
std::deque<int_pair_t> chosen;
foreach_( int_pair_t p, chosen )

// Or (as commented by Arne Mertz)
typedef std::deque<std::pair<int, int>> container_t;
container_t chosen;
foreach_(container_t::value_type p, chosen)
```

Possible replacements, both introduced in c++11, are:

- [range-for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) loop:

  ```
  for (auto& : chosen)
  {
  }
  ```
- [lambdas](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda):

  ```
  std::for_each(std::begin(chosen),
                std::end(chosen)
                [](std::pair<int, int>& p)
                {
                });
  ```

Comment: Another typedef solution would be to typedef the container and then use `Cont::value_type`. That way you'll have to change only one place if you change the containerelements, e.g. to `std::pair<int, long>`

Answer (score 4):

Boosts `foreach` is a *macro*, which means it's handled by the preprocessor. And the preprocessor is pretty simple, and can't handle symbols with commas in them as it is used as a macro argument separator.