# Passing a template which requires a comma to a single-argument macro

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I have some code that essentially condenses down to

```
#define FOO(a)
FOO(std::map<int, int>);
```

But it emits a compile error (too many actual parameters for macro `FOO`).

Obviously the preprocessor is thinking that I've supplied `std::map<int` and `int>` as arguments.

Is there a way round this? The preprocessor will not treat a quoted string with a comma in this way.

Comment: One easy way is to define a macro that resolves to comma. Another solution, when that's suitable, is to pass the template name and template arguments separately. However, I recall that Johannes Schaub had a neat trick for this that was more general. Now I'm just wringing my brain to try to remember it. No luck so far... :(

Comment: Boss says I should just chill out and use a typedef. But that's rather boring.

Comment: How about [BOOST_PP_COMMA](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24793828/1708801)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comma in C/C++ macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842468/comma-in-c-c-macro)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass multi-argument templates to macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942912/how-to-pass-multi-argument-templates-to-macros)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should perhaps ideally be a comment, but SO doesn't support code in comments, so, you *can* do

```
#include <map>

#define T_ARGS( ... ) < __VA_ARGS__ >

#define FOO( a )  a x;

auto main() -> int
{
    FOO( std::map T_ARGS( int, int ) );
    (void) x;
}
```

or you can define a macro that resolves to comma, or you can use just about any scheme that's specific to some particular use case (e.g., passing template name separately).

Comment: Accepted since, somehow, this just seems more elegant than defining something to a comma.

Answer (score 4):

The [comma is being treated as a macro argument seperator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24793828/1708801), it does not do this with commas within parenthesizes.

If you are using Boost, they provide [BOOST_PP_COMMA](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/comma.html):

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/punctuation/comma.hpp>

#define FOO(a)
FOO(std::map<int BOOST_PP_COMMA int>);
```

You can also define your own:

```
#define COMMA ,
FOO(std::map<int COMMA int>);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add an extra set of parentheses:

```
#define FOO(a)
FOO((std::map<int, int>));
```

Answer (score 1):

The preprocessor will only treat unparenthesised commas as a macro argument separator. So what you can do is rewrite `std::map<int, int>` into something that has parentheses around it. A simple one might be `decltype(std::map<int, int>())`.