# Parenthesis in templated type macro argument and I cannot use variadic macros

Tags: c++, templates, macros, c++03

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Trouble with template parameters used in macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295890/trouble-with-template-parameters-used-in-macros)

I'm trying to figure out a way to get this to work without changing the structure of `INHERIT`:

```
#define INHERIT(t) foo<t>
template<typename A, typename B>
struct bar : INHERIT(bar<A, B>) {};
```

The problem is that the invocation of `INHERIT` contains a comma.

I'm trying to support older compilers so variadic macros and template aliases are not an option. Is there anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a little tricky macros:

```
#define A2(t1,t2) t1,t2
#define A3(t1,t2,t3) t1,t2,t3
#define A4(t1,t2,t3,t4) t1,t2,t3,t4
#define INHERIT(t) foo< t >
template<typename A, typename B>
struct bar : INHERIT(bar<A2(A, B)>) {};
```

These macros cause that preprocessor stop treating comma as its syntax - the comma starts be treated as just part of argument.

An alternative way:

```
#define bar_A_B bar<A,B>
template<typename A, typename B>
struct bar : INHERIT(bar_A_B) {};
```

**NOTE**
These examples these does not compile without:

```
template <class T>
class foo {};
```

Comment: still doesn't compile on vs2012. error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '<'

Comment: @billz is `foo<T>` missing in your program?

Comment: [Works for me](http://liveworkspace.org/code/9f46f040323deb75b9738529173704a2)