# C++ too few arguments for class template "*" when it's wrapped in a macro

Tags: c++, templates, macros, template-meta-programming

Here is my code.

```
#define mp_eval(Func)       Func::value

template<int L, int R>
struct StaticMinimum
{
    static const int value = (L < R) ? L : R;
};
// Error: too few arguments for class template "StaticMinimum"
cout << mp_eval(StaticMinimum<9, 12>) << endl;
```

Isn't `mp_eval(StaticMinimum<9, 12>)` to be replaced as `StaticMinimum<9, 12>::value` by the compiler? I think I must miss something. Please let me know what happened.

Comment: Have you looked at the preprocessed output? Have a look at this: http://ideone.com/GuDwei

Comment: You can't pass a comma in a macro argument unless you put parentheses around the whole argument.

Comment: Could you replace the macro by an inline function or template function?

Comment: @MattMcNabb I've thought it over. But I still don't know how to. Could you tell me how you deal with it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trouble with template parameters used in macros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295890/trouble-with-template-parameters-used-in-macros)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The comma when using the macro (`mp_eval(StaticMinimum<9, 12>)`) is parsed as an argument separator.

The macro could be fixed as:

```
#define mp_eval(...)       __VA_ARGS__::value
```

In C++1y you could use variable templates instead of macros.

Answer (score 4):

The preprocessor sees the comma between 9 and 12 as separating arguments to the macro.

Wrap the expression in additional `()` to stop this.

```
cout << mp_eval((StaticMinimum<9, 12>)) << endl;
```

UPDATE: As pointed out in the comments by Ggicci, this solution is not possible in this specific case: it will result in `(StaticMinimum<9, 12>)::value` which is not valid C++.

Comment: This solution does not fix this situation, since it will cause another problem: `'value' : is not a member of '\`global namespace''` or `'value' : undeclared identifier`. Like `(StaticMinimum<9, 12>)::value` does.